# Unhandled exception was generated

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I have a website in which some pages are in ASP and some pages are in ASP.Net, But my problem is 
when i execute it on my Local PC then it is working 
But when I execute it from  Our Server then Got Error " unhandled exception was generated during the execution of 
the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using 
the exception stack trace below."

and This  i come in only ASP.Net Pages.

Help me, 
Thnx in Advance

Comment: and that stack trace below says what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This is often caused by lack of permissions to write to the file system on the web server, but it can really be caused by anything that differs from your development environment.

There is an error/exception available somewhere that will help you diagnose and correct the problem and you need to find that error.  One place to look is the Windows Event Log.  Another thing to check is how your web.config file sets the value for CustomErrors.

Are you seeing something like this at all?

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/images/yellow-screen-of-death-large.png